# Is it allowed to be an Apple trusted developer with pure Java

Tags: macos, install, java, gatekeeper, notarization

I am developing JavaFX with Spring applications that are shipped with native installers for Windows, Linux and macOS. I am hosting the macOS DMG and pkg installers outside Mac App Store on my web site.

When I download and attempt to install a DMG on my macOS Mojave, the latter forbids to install because the app is not from a trusted Apple developer. Downloading the same installer from FTP is allowed by Mac to be installed.

My question is - Can I have my package installer signed (by registering as an Apple developer) if the application is purely Java and has nothing to do with Apple specific SDKs?

Answer (score 3):

Basically if I understand your question - yes, it’s allowed, but might not be required.

When you pay to be a developer, Apple generates a secure certificate you can use for many functions - one of which is to code sign a folder of files. Applications on macOS are just bundles of files with some conventions which files make something a package or an app. You can sign a script, package,  interpreted code bundle or a compiled app.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution

Apple is offering additional items like notarizing an app but you should be able to sign your example app with a self-generated certificate before you pay for Apple to sign / provide your identity that all of their devices and OS will trust as valid.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution

To recap, you pay for an identity that Apple validates. Of course if you abuse this, your certificate can and should be revoked but as long as you are signing legitimate apps you should expect to only have to pay annually for a renewal of your certificate. This is pretty much analogous to getting an SSL cert. You pay for those periodically, and then the signer generally doesn’t care why / where you install that cert - as long as you don’t break their rules and get caught, they don’t revoke your certificate.

Now - if the java executable gets notarized and signed by someone else, you might not need this at all and you’re not embedding executable bits and just resources and text or source code. For example, it doesn’t make sense to pay if you write swift scripts or python scripts or bash (or other shell) scripts. That would be like code signing a word doc and not word the program itself.

Comment: Thanks. I shall give it a try becoming an Apple developer.

Answer (score 0):

Signing with Apple Developer ID worked out. DMGs and PKGs are created and installed just fine on MacOS, well up to version 10.14. From **macOS 10.15** Apple made developers notarize their applications otherwise Gatekeeper will not allow them to be installed. I am using [SnifX frameworks](https://snifx.lazyweaver.com/) which simply creates and bundles via Maven a Spring-based Java application to a macOS DMG or PKG with a bundled JRE inside. The current status quo - Apple notarization attempts fail Java bundled applications due to **"Hardened Runtime capability"** and **"The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK."** issues on bundled Java binaries.
From what I researched and attempted:

- The hardened runtime issue is fixed by enabling the corresponding option on the signing command : `codesign --force --deep --options runtime -s 'Your Apple Developer ID' -v YourJavaBundledApp.dmg`;
- About "SDK older than the 10.9 SDK" - looks like it is required to unpack each Jar/Zip from JRE bundle and apply forced signing and then re-assemble the Jar/Zip. Maybe a better way exists, but this seams like another topic (how to notarize non-XCode applications with bundled runtimes inside)...

Comment: No need to do all that because the problem is in the JDK. At least for JDK 8 it is still not solved: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223671